# Have I called the onAuthStateChanged function incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
githubLogin.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider();

    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
        var user = result.user;
        console.log(user);
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            if (user) {
                window.location = "pages/welcome.html";
            }});
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

});
```

So the problem is that, when I redirect the user to welcome and I see that there's no user logged in on that page. 
I know I've got to use the onAuthStateChanged() function but I've got it wrong so far. Can I know how this can be done? and also I've got something similar for google login, is that affecting the function?

Answer (score 1):

You should determine the Auth state before you show the button. If `onAuthStateChanged` listener initially triggers with a null user, you display the login screen.

Also when you call `signInWithPopup`, you don't need to add the state change listener. You can just do:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  // User logged in, you can get currentUser from onAuthStateChanged
  // listener on welcome page.
  window.location.assign("pages/welcome.html");
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle error.
});
```

Comment: I've done something like this..... but it didn't seem to work again..

https://codepen.io/kol730/pen/QqWBZz

Comment: Please provide details.

Comment: I just added the link above

Comment: You are misusing `onAuthStateChanged` listener. Did you add that listener on your welcome page? You only show your sign in code and not the code where the signed in user lands. Also describe what you are experiencing. Did the redirect to the welcome page work? if so, the user should be signed in but you are failing to detect it on the welcome page.

Comment: i've done this when the user is redirected to the welcome page.

const fireUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user){
  fireUser = user;
  document.getElementById('welcome-message').innerHTML = firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName;
})

Comment: Yeah, I understood my mistake. Thanks for your help.