# How to use onAuthStateChange in multiple js files with webpack

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use `onAuthStateChange` from firebase authentication to get the information about the user currently logged in, in order to get a document in my Firestore database (that contains all the informations about the selected user).

At, I started by doing it on my header.js that contains the header used everywhere across my app, and I was doing DOM modifications directly in the function, like this example:

```
let userData = "";

onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
    if (user) {
        console.log(user);
        const userDoc = await getDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid));
        userData = { uid: userDoc.id, ...userDoc.data() };
        elements.userFirstname.textContent = userData.firstname;
    } else {
        elements.loginButton.style.display = "block";
        elements.userDropdown.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

But this is not scalable at all, because I have user content to display also in the body of the page. So I'm thinking to make `userData` a global variable that I can re-use everywhere by doing an import. However, the import is made far before `onAuthStateChanged` is done.

This seems to be a recurrent thing people needs when using Firebase authentication, however I don't find any explanations on how to do it properly.

Comment: It sounds like you're making the assumption that having multiple auth state observers in your app is definitely a bad idea.  I don't think that's necessarily true.  It's very common in modern applications for multiple parts of a software system to "listen" or "observe" the changes to single source of data so that the application state can be correctly modeled no matter what changes in that data, whenever it changes.  Pushing that into a global variable might help a bit, but it doesn't let any of the code that uses the global data to react to its changes.  This is why we have observer patterns.

Comment: The actual use case is not clear but useing `onAuthStateChanged ` is really for listening to changes in the current user state. Throughout your app though, if you need to get the current user, this `const user = auth.currentUser;` is simpler and if it's nil, the user is not signed in. Obviously implementing `onAuthStateChanged` is a safe use because your app will know if the user is signed in or not making is safe to call `auth.currentUser`. So what makes your existing code `not scalable?`

Comment: It's true that I could re-use multiple times `onAuthStateChange` and maybe it's what people usually do? I didn't found a good example for now, but I know this is a very common need that I have here. For me, what makes the code not scalable is that I'm doing the `getDoc` on Firestore database with onAuthStateChange and I would avoid doing it everytime I need to get something in a different file (header.js, myfile.js, footer.js etc...). Ideally, I want to do `onAuthStateChange` once, getting my document and store it somewhere so I do only one call to Firebase.

Comment: You only need to call it it once - and in fact, you don't really need to call it at all. As mentioned, auth.currentUser will contain the current user and indicate whether the user is logged in or not. If so, then load the data from Firebase. If not, ask them to Auth. Once Firebase is polled for the needed data, store it in a global var (or however you want to do it) - that process is not related to Firebase though as that's just app level code. Is there something more?

Comment: Yes: `auth.currentUser` takes time to be filled with current user uid right? So I have to wait for it, then do my call in my database to get all the user informations (here again, async). It's the result of this call that I will store in a global variable. But how am I suppose to ask other functions in other files to wait for the global variable to contain the informations (so, the promise of the database call fullfilled), to do my DOM updates with user data?

Comment: The general thought here is the `onAuthStateChanged` is used on initial app start as during that process, there could a delay in populating the user. However,  once the user is populated `auth.currentUser` will remain populated and can be used throughout the app. However, depending on the app design `onAuthStateChanged` may be needed in different views - in case the user logs out in one view, another view doesn't attempt to access data. The important bit is that during the app run, currentUser will be nil if they are not logged in. So, you can use the listener or check for nil.

Comment: I guess I will have a problem making `auth.currentUser` available in the other javascript files that I'm using in my page. But first, maybe I have a problem in the way I'm doing `onAuthStateChanged`. Because currently I'm doing this in my header, however the rest of my JS continues to load, but if we need user info, `auth.currentUser` is of course `null`. How do you suggest to manage authentication?

Comment: There are a number of solutions - both questions and answer posted here on SO that could be a workable workflow. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65870414/firebase-onauthstatechanged-keeps-refreshing) and perhaps [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46189632/have-i-called-the-onauthstatechanged-function-incorrectly) and maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73286922/after-onauthstatechanged-still-currentuser-is-null)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand any of the link provided unfortunately. The thing is, I just want to do one call to onAuthStateChanged, to be able to get `auth.currentUser`, then rely on it on every file that calls the header js file, where it's initiated. The thing is that I'm not going to pass all the possible functions in the `onAuthStateChanged` callback, how can I do to delay the use of each function that needs user's data, to after the callback of onAuthStateChanged is done?

Comment: I see a lot of similar explanations like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71669571/currentuser-is-returning-null) however they almost all recommend to do my things **inside** the callback. But that would mean I need on every page and every JS file of my app to fire onAuthStateChange, sometimes multiple times per page (if I have 2-3 js files to generate the entire page). I'm not sure it's the right way and it sounds weird to me.

Comment: Is there a way potentially, to integrate in a systematic way the loading of every page of my webpack app inside a `onAuthStateChange` or maybe wait for the `authStateReady()` promise to load my page?